# onlick submit button working properly on chrome driver, but redirecting to login page in IE driver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver

While using selenium webdriver in chrome, the submit button works properly and all the data from the form is displayed properly when it is clicked.

But when i use IE , the button momentarily redirects to the desired page but then to the login page.

I did some work around and cleared cache of chrome browser, then tried submitting the form, it navigated to the login page, so i think this is the issue with IE,
but i don't know how to take care of it.

```
       WebDriver driver;

        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();



        cap.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOR, UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.IGNORE);
        cap.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION, true);
        cap.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true);
        cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
        cap.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IGNORE_ZOOM_SETTING, true); 
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(cap);
driver.get("my url");

WebElement username, password, Iagree;
username = driver.findElements(By.name("USER")).get(0);
username.clear();
username.sendKeys("user");

password = driver.findElements(By.name("PASSWORD")).get(0);
password.clear();
password.sendKeys("pass");

Iagree = driver.findElements(By.xpath("login")).get(0);
Iagree.click();
System.out.println("Login Completed!");


Thread.sleep(5000);

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='userid']")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='userid']")).sendKeys("abc");

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='xxxx']")).sendKeys("ert");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='xxxx']")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='xxxx']")).sendKeys("xxxx");

// after many more fields, there's a submit button.


WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='Submit']"));

element.click();

/*JavascriptExecutor js=(JavascriptExecutor)driver;

js.executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");*/
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10000);
wait.until( new Predicate<WebDriver>() { public boolean apply(WebDriver driver) { return ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete"); } } );

/*JavascriptExecutor jse=(JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
*/



/*Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.moveToElement(element).perform();
builder.click().perform();*/
```

so this works properly on chrome but not on IE11

Kindly help.

Comment: oh trust me on this, i did a lot of googling and did a lot of  r & d on this, asking a question here was my last resort.

Comment: We have no way of knowing this so do show what you found and discarded so we are not wasting our and your time presenting stuff you already tried

Comment: added code, any help appreciated

Comment: Please close all the existing IE browsers and then run your script. If you are using any framework to launch the scripts then make sure you open the framework in chrome/firefox to launch the scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide your code? It seems the request post problems.Remember the following rules:

1. if the button didn't set a type, when clicked the form would be posted automatically.
2. if didn't set a action url, the browser would add a `?` after the current url and refreshed the page.[The consequence looks like you were tripped]
3. if you need post the form by ajax, you need to set button `type='button'`, or `return false;`

Hope this will helpful to you...